# Can a moderator moves a question with an open bounty?

Tags: discussion, questions, bounties

This question [Xapian vs ApacheSolr](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16302/xapian-vs-apachesolr) clearly doesn't belong here and should be moved to SO but there's an open bounty.

Can a moderator move it to SO ? I think the user would have better answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moderators can, in some circumstances, refund the bounty; once the bounty is refunded, the question can be moved to another site. As the closing dialog doesn't allow to vote for the migration to Stack Overflow, this is something a moderator needs to do; moderators can migrate a question to any site.
Flag the question for moderation attention; if the moderators think the question should be migrated, they will do the necessary.

Comment: Seems the question had been moved to SO ;)